# Possible combinations of items in toolbox types

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some js that has 2 sets of data.

Toolboxes: an array of objects that have name and number of spaces for large, medium and small tools.

Tools: an array of objects with name and size.

I've looked at a few posts with show recursive functions to get all the combinations but they refer to numbers. I'm trying to output all combinations of what each toolbox can possibly fit in the different slots. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
tools = [{
"Name": "Spanner",
"Size": "Large",
},
{
"Name": "Pliers",
"Size": "Large",
},
{
"Name": "Mallet",
"Size": "Large",
},
{
"Name": "Hammer",
"Size": "Medium",
},
{
"Name": "Pliers",
"Size": "Large",
},
{
"Name": "Screwdriver",
"Size": "Medium",
},
{
"Name": "Tweezers",
"Size": "Small",
},
{
"Name": "Saw",
"Size": "Medium",
}]

toolboxes = [{
"Name": "Bertha",
"Large": 2,
"Medium": 1,
"Small": 3,
},
{
"Name": "Xetha",
"Large": 2,
"Medium": 2,
"Small": 2,
},
{
"Name": "Decker",
"Large": 2,
"Medium": 1,
"Small": 2,
},
{
"Name": "Woodhammer",
"Large": 2,
"Medium": 1,
"Small": 3,
}];
```

Comment: Belongs on: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think you just need to figure out how you'd do this with pencil and paper first.